# VB.NET Defrag Complete Notification

Tags: vb.net, defragmentation

Is there an event or other means by which a VB.NET program can be notified when a Windows 7 defrag has completed (so the program can instruct the PC to shut down)?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [EventLog.EntryWritten](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten.aspx) event to monitor for events. On Windows 7, an event in `Application` log with `Source = "Defrag"` may indicate completion of defragmentation. You can then examine the id - should be 258, and description will say something like `The disk defragmenter successfully completed defragmentation on (C:)`.

Here is a screenshot from my home PC to prove the above:

[image]